# Homological criteria for finite generation and finite presentation of modules?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

(I'm new here; if I'm doing something wrong please help me out.)

In short, my question is: There are some results on the behavior of finite generation and finite presentation in exact sequences (of modules over an arbitrary commutative ring A), which feel like they come from a long exact sequence in homology. Is there some homology theory or something that explains this?

OK, first some motivation.  Here are some facts (which I ran across in Matsumura's CRT).

Suppose

$0 \rightarrow L \rightarrow M \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0$

is an exact sequence of A-modules, A a commutative ring.  Then we have:

1. If M is finitely generated then N is finitely generated. (Trivial.)
2. If L and N are finitely generated then M is finitely generated. (Trivial.)
3. If N is finitely presented, and M is finitely generated, then L is finitely generated.  (Theorem 2.6)
4. If M is finitely presented, and L is finitely generated, then N is finitely presented.  (Exercise 2.5b)
5. If L and N are finitely presented then so is M.  (Exercise 2.5a)

We can generalize these results as follows.  (Also, there's another post where part of the generalized result was discussed.)
[Generalization of finitely generated, finitely presented modules?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93668/generalization-of-finitely-generated-finitely-presented-modules)

Say a module $M$ is of type $FL_n$ if there is an exact sequence

$A^{k_n} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow A^{k_0} \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$.

Note that $FL_0$ means finitely generated, and $FL_1$ means finitely presented.

Let $L$, $M$, $N$ be in an exact sequence as above, and consider the sequence of statements:

..., $L$ is $FL_1$, $M$ is $FL_1$, $N$ is $FL_1$, $L$ is $FL_0$, $M$ is $FL_0$, $N$ is $FL_0$, (true).

The general fact is that any statement is this sequence is implied by its two neighbors.  (For instance, if $M$ is $FL_1$ and $L$ is $FL_0$ then $N$ is $FL_1$.)  This can be proven by induction and the snake lemma (unless I made a mistake!).  The five results above are special cases of this general fact.

> Now for my question: Is this general fact a consequence of a long exact sequence in homology?  If there were some homology theory such that $H_i(M)$ could detect whether $M$ was of type $FL_i$, the fact would follow immediately. (Maybe $M$ is of type $FL_i$ if and only if $H_i(M)$ is finitely generated, for instance.)  Is there such a theory?

One last remark: this post (finitely presented implies always finitely presented, [Does "finitely presented" mean "always finitely presented"?  (Answered: Yes!)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1788/does-finitely-presented-mean-always-finitely-presented-answered-yes)) also makes me feel like there might be something interesting going on, even though I can't say precisely what.

Comment: If $A$ is a non-negatively graded and connected over a field $k$, and your modules are graded with bounded below graduations, then you can use $H_i (M)=Tor^A(k,M)$: a module is $FL_n$ if $H_i(M)$ is finite dimensional for $i \leq n$. If you want zero cohomology groups, you can notice that $H_i$ takes values in graded vector spaces, and compose it with the functor which localizes at the Serre subcategory of finite dimensional graded vector spaces —call $H'$ the composition; now a module is in $FL_n$ if $H_i'(M)=0$ for $i\leq n$.

Answer (score 3):

This question makes sense, but it is not clear how to give an answer in view of the state of (my) current knowledge. Namely, I don't know of such a (co)homology theory, but I don't know if there isn't one. I haven't tried, nor do I want to try, to make a counter example.

I suggest you go and look at the literature. In particular the material in SGA 6 concerning pseudo-coherent complexes. Namely, what you call an $FL_n$ module is a $(-n)$-pseudo-coherent module, see [Section Tag 064N](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/064N). The definition applies to objects of the derived category of modules, and there one has a [more general result for distinguished triangles](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/064R).